# How do I handle parameterized sql query in ItemWriter?

Tags: sql, spring-batch

Trying to figure out how to use parameterized sql update query in ItemWriter class.

I see error:

```
Invalid parameter 1: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

```
public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<Assessment> {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;

    private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = :var1, COLUMN2 = :var2 WHERE COLUMN = 'TEST'";


    public ExpireAssessmentWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.namedJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Assessment> list) throws Exception {
        for (Assessment assessment : list) {
           
                 Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                 paramMap.put("var1", assessment.getVar1());
                 paramMap.put("var2", assessment.getVar2());
                namedJdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_QUERY, paramMap);
                throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am creating a custom writer in order to write to three different tables but get an error using the namedJdbcTemplate

Comment: You need to use named parameters. see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you create a custom writer for that. The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` provided by Spring Batch already supports named parameters.

You can find several examples in the [JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilderTests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/d8fc58338d3b059b67b5f777adc132d2564d7402/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilderTests.java#L53).

Comment: Im trying to write to 3 different tables. Can the item writer take multiple insert queries?

Comment: ok, but that's a key point which was not mentioned in your question. In that case, you might need a custom writer with a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks, I added a quick edit for better explanation. 
I get an error using the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. is it formed correctly?

Comment: in your edit, you are throwing an exception right after the update statement. Is that intended? This is not really related to spring batch, it's a question about the usage of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` from Spring framework. You can find examples here:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplateTests.java

Comment: Thanks, I was using the exception to test. It is working now thanks to your suggestion about using a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.